# Embedding Felix in Tomcat

Tags: apache-felix

I am a newbie to OSGi, started using felix. I am at present well versed with the concept of bundles, service etc. I have a requirement where I can embed Felix into Tomcat, I tried googling the same but was unable to find a relevant solution for my purpose.

What I exactly need is.. 
Till now I used to deploy my web app bundles into embedded http jetty service/PAX web.. installed inside Felix, but now I want to put Felix into Apache Tomcat/any other application server, so that whenever my tomcat starts up I need my felix instance up and running, and at the same time should be able to deploy/install/start my bundles through felix.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First off, Use of "ASAP" is bad form. Secondly, what have you tried? Have you tried googling "felix war file" or "osgi war file" or something like that? There are a bunch of results there.

Comment: Hi James, I tried searching with "Embedding Felix in Tomcat", "Felix inside tomcat", but the results were helpless..

Answer (score 8):

You might want to consider the Apache Sling Launchpad subproject. This creates a WAR file which can be deployed into any servlet container and which launches the Apache Felix framework as the OSGi framework.

See also the [Sling Launchpad](http://sling.apache.org/site/the-sling-launchpad.html) and [Embedding Sling](http://sling.apache.org/site/embedding-sling.html) for more information.